# Keep me well and I stay whole, What am I?

Tags: riddle

This should be hard riddle.

> Keep me well and I stay whole,
>
> As I am fit, I keep my role.
>
> Around me, people you see,
>
> Light’s away and the crowd will sway.
>
> Feeling your breath I love,
>
> Gives me pearls, I see blurred.
>
> Comfort and joy you get from me,
>
> Always taking what I have.
>
> Around my twins, ordinary I am,
>
> So take us home, make us your own.
>
> When I fall, it breaks my heart,
>
> Forever scared I will be.
>
> And when I die, dry faces I see,
>
> Never can you fix your blunder.
>
> But now, I return to where I'm from,
>
> And Then again, Part of me you might see.

Comment: Is it a snowman?

Comment: NOP, Its not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be

> Sand Clock (Hourglass)

Keep me well and I stay whole,

As I am fit, I keep my role.

> If you take care of the sand clock then it working well and reused indefinitely by inverting the bulbs once the upper bulb is empty.

Light’s away and the crowd will sway.

> Without light you can't measure of time.

Feeling your breath I love,

Gives me pearls, I see blurred.

> Not sure about this.

Comfort and joy you get from me,

Always taking what I have.

> You can measure the correct length of time using a sand clock.

Around my twins, ordinary I am,

So take us home, make us your own.

> It has two glass bulbs connected vertically by a narrow neck. That allows a regulated trickle of sand from the upper bulb to the lower one.

When I fall, it breaks my heart,

Forever scared I will be.

> When the upper bulb is empty, it break the time measuring and very fragile.

And when I die, dry faces I see,

Never can you fix your blunder.

> When you not inverting the bulbs, you can't fix the time.

But now, I return to where I'm from,

And Then again, Part of me you might see.

> Inverting the bulbs once the upper bulb is empty and see the time.

Comment: Good @rsp. Expected Right Answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a:

> A Birthday Candle

Keep me well and I stay whole,

> If you take care of the candle then it stays whole.

As I am fit, I keep my role.

> A candle that hasn't been used completely can still be reused.

Light’s away and the crowd will sway.

> When you blow out the light of the birthday candle then everyone are happy and may jump and clap or even sway when they sing happy birthday.

Feeling your breath I love,

> Its a birthday candle... its purpose is for you to blow it out.

Gives me pearls, I see blurred.

> While the candle is used the warm wax slides to the side of the candle and can create "pearls" of wax.

Comfort and joy you get from me,

> You are happy when you celebrate a birthday

Always taking what I have.

> By lighting the candle the fire uses the wax as fuel.
> We are taking away the candle wax.

Around my twins, ordinary I am,

> Near other candles a candle seems a bit ordinary.

So take us home, make us your own.

> Buy some candles for your own birthday.

When I fall, it breaks my heart,

> When a candle fall it can break, you even have candles shaped like a heart.

Forever scared I will be.

> Not sure about this one...

And when I die, dry faces I see,

> If you leave the candle alone then by the time it is finished the party will be over and people will be less excited now.

Never can you fix your blunder.

> If you fail to blow out the candle you can't fix that, only try again.

But now, I return to where I'm from,

> Wherever you store you birthday candles.

And Then again, Part of me you might see.

> If you store what is left of the candle then you might see it again in the next birthday.

Comment: Wow, Nice guess, Unique thought. But not the answer. But +1 for your Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a:

> Pen

Keep me well and I stay whole,

As I am fit, I keep my role.

> If you break a pen, you cannot write with it anymore

Light’s away and the crowd will sway.

> When there is a dim light, people oscillate to be able to read (I'm having a hard time with this one)

Feeling your breath I love,

Gives me pearls, I see blurred.

> People commonly breath on a pen, when it is dry. Breath on a surface creates droplets (pearls) and through plastic one can see it as a blur

Comfort and joy you get from me,

Always taking what I have.

> You use a pen to write and draw... with its ink

Around my twins, ordinary I am,

So take us home, make us your own.

> Pens are very common, and can be taken home

When I fall, it breaks my heart,

Forever scared I will be.

> Pens may have problems when they fall, starting to leak ink from the sphere for example

And when I die, dry faces I see,

Never can you fix your blunder.

> Nobody cries when a pen is without ink

But now, I return to where I'm from,

And Then again, Part of me you might see.

> Plastic is recyclable and it's possible that you see the same plastic... on another pen :P

Comment: No, Also this is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a huge stretch..

> Armed Forces

Keep me well and I stay whole,

As I am fit, I keep my role.

> Army Soldiers remain in their role till their retirement(Fit)

Around me, people you see,

Light’s away and the crowd will sway.

> The Army's contribution isn't highlighted as much as others.

Feeling your breath I love,

Gives me pearls, I see blurred.

Comfort and joy you get from me

> The Armymen live for the country and die for the country, all the while protecting their fellow countrymen..

Always taking what I have.

Around my twins, ordinary I am,

> The twins of the army might refer to the navy and the air force. We sort of take all them to be granted..

So take us home, make us your own.

When I fall, it breaks my heart,

> Army veterans are perfectionists.. They never like to fail.

Forever scared I will be.

And when I die, dry faces I see,

Never can you fix your blunder.

> The death of An Army veteran evokes emotions among his countrymen. Blunder might refer to the fact that they are usually overlooked..

But now, I return to where I'm from,

And Then again, Part of me you might see.

> Not sure about this, maybe they return to their heavenly abode??